# XMLDocument.Load() Does not load the file while running test project

Tags: c#-4.0, nunit

I have a test case which validates an XML file.
When using VS2010 with .Net 3.5 framework, the below code works perfectly fine, i am able to load the XML file. My file is location is Source folder of the application.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            doc.Load("Terms_and_Conditions.xml");

            XmlNode node;

            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            //Select and display the value of the element.
            node = root.SelectSingleNode(NodeSelection);

            return node.InnerText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Solution Folder:
[image]

When I run the same code in .Net 4.6.1, file path resolves to 
     `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\Terms_and_Conditions.xml`

Anyone have an idea why this issue with .Net 4.6.1

Comment: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1072

Comment: Thank. the above link helped.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your unit tests run in the test runner, which is located in the Common7 folder and not in your projects bin folder. Since you specify a relative path to the xml file, the program will look for the file in the current folder, which is the Common7 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the quick help.

Here is how I solved the problem with above link.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    var path = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory).ToString());

    doc.Load("Terms_and_Conditions.xml");

    XmlNode node;

    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    //Select and display the value of the element.
    node = root.SelectSingleNode(NodeSelection);

    return node.InnerText;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```